# I'm having trouble understanding how is this line of code filtering a pandas dataframe's rows

Tags: python, pandas, filter

I understand that first i'm assigning the csv file's content to the dataframe, but i dont understand what exactly the lambda function is doing to not select the rows that have the value of 'None' in the 'Fat' column.

```
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv',delimiter=';')

filtered_data = data[lambda row:row.Fat != 'None']
```

Comment: `lambda` functions as an anonymous function, right there in the code. Compare to a function `def filter_none(row): return True if value.Fat != 'None' else False`. You thus get a `True` or `False` value for each row, and your `data` is filtered on that.

Comment: Though I much prefer something like `filtered_data = data[data.Fat != 'None']`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is using the [selection by callable](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#selection-by-callable) feature of dataframes. You can pass a callable (such as a function) as the index to select a subset.

The `lambda` is just a shorthand to create a function, ie. you could also write:

```
def is_fat(row):
    return row.Fat != 'None'
```

and use that function for indexing:

```
filtered_data = data[is_fat]
```

As you can see, the `lambda` function basically returns `False` for rows that has `'None'` in the column `Fat`, and `True` otherwise.